# Error 206 occures on JUnit test in Eclipse

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit

I have a problem when i try to run JUnit test class in Eclipse.

> Exception occurred executing command line.
>   Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\User\Documents\Projects\MyProject"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

After I received this error I started to search how to fix the problem... However now I generated MANIFEST file that contains all of the jars that i need, but I don't know how to pass the new manifest file to the project and also what to do with the jars in my lib dir?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I have SimpleTest class and TestRunner class

```
public class SimpleTest {

     @Test
       public void testAssertions() {

          String str1 = new String ("abc");
          String str2 = new String ("abc");

          assertEquals(str1, str2);       
     }
    }

package com.epb.junit;

import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(SimpleTest.class);
      for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
         System.out.println(failure.toString());
      }
      System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
   }
}
```

Nothing interesting here, I just need to know how to pack all of my JAR files which I am using, because they are too many... I made a manifest file with all of them but I don't know how to pass it instead of JAR files.

P.S I am running the test class with Eclipse -> Run As -> JUnit Test option. After the error occured I've made this TestRunner class and I am running it as Java Application but still Error 206.
From the things that I read I realized that my Build Path is too long, because there are a lot of JARS so now I'm looking to find a way to shorten this Path and to pack the jars into one. I've tried to export the lib folder into Jar file but it doesn't worked.

EDIT 2

The last thing that I tried just before a moment is to create a "pathing jar" which contains only Manifest.mf file inside it. I put this jar in my project Build Path instead of all other Jars but still no result... now the project has errors for the Built Path...

Comment: Nowhere near enough information in your question to answer. Please share more details about your test class, how you are running it, why your JAR is relevant, ...

Comment: Problem solved! https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=327193

Comment: That's good news. Please post an answer to your own question. You can then accept it after 48 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is to follow these steps:

1. Copy your eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.launching_3.4.*.jar to a safe
   place outside of the plugins folder, so that you always have a way to revert.
2. Close Eclipse.
3. Rename the *.jar to *.zip
4. Open the zip file and copy the 4 class files from the **attachment** to
   org\eclipse\jdt\internal\launching (replace existing files)
5. Go to META-INF in the zip file and delete all files except MANIFEST.MF
6. Extract MANIFEST.MF to your disk and edit it with a text editor.
7. Remove everything starting from the first "NAME:" entry.
8. Make sure you leave *two* (2) line break characters at the end of the file!
9. Save the MANIFEST.MF and copy it back into the zip file.
10. Rename the *.zip back to *.jar
11. Replace the modified jar with the jar in you Eclipse/plugin directory!
12. Enjoy!

PS. **ATTACHMENT** from step 4 can be downloaded from here:

> https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=216637

Thanks to Mr.Markus Keller who created those steps!

Comment: which 4 classes need to copy, as i see many class but not able to figure it out the four classes ?

Comment: I have Eclipse JEE Indigo SR2 (x64), I have some GWT projects open and, when starting Eclipse, I was getting the same error message from DataNucleus Enhancer. I'm too glad to know the steps described in this answer work as well for this version of Eclipse, the only difference being the version number of the jar to be backed up (3.6 instead of 3.4). The classes to use to replace (namely LongCommandLineLauncher.class, StandardVMDebugger$ConnectRunnable.class, StandardVMDebugger.class and StandardVMRunner.class) are indeed newer than original ones though attachment is from version 3.5 of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by performing the following:

Select Project ⟶ Properties ⟶ Google App Engine ⟶ ORM and only include directories that contains classes that you want to enhance.