# Error=7, Argument list too long in IntelliJ Idea in Ubuntu

Tags: java, intellij-idea

While running a JAR application in IntelliJ IDEA in Linux OS I am getting this error :
***error=7, Argument list too long.***
I tried adding a property in .idea/workspace.xml as:
 but there has been no change.
Also, there is no such option in the run configuration settings to shorten the command line if I run this as a JAR application.
[image]
Also, I tried to run this as an application and had used the option shorten command line but then also there has been no change.

Comment: You may like to refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876974/cannot-run-program-error-7-argument-list-too-long.